# Confused upon how threejs works

Tags: html, css, three.js, 3d

I have used example code in this html/css code with a script that aims to create a 3D cube using three.js.

When I open the HTML file I get a blank page in chrome with just, "canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }"

Here is my code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My first Three.js app</title> &lt;style>canvas { width: 100%; 
height: 100% }</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var scene = new THREE.Scene();
         var camera = new 
THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1,10000);
         var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, 
window.innerHeight);document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
         var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(700, 700, 700, 10, 10, 10);
         var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xfffff, 
wireframe: true});
         var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); scene.add(cube);
         function render() {
             requestAnimationFrame(render);
             cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
             cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
             renderer.render(scene, camera);
         }
         render();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't provide an image of your code.  Copy and paste it into the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your camera is probably starting out inside the cube.

Try adding:

camera.position.set (0,0,1000)

And maybe:

camera.lookAt (new THREE.Vector3 (0,0,0))

after you create the camera.

Another option is to just Run the following snippet and then examine it for clues:

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var w = 300;
var h = 200;
renderer.setSize( w,h );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
 45,  // Field of view
 w/h, // Aspect ratio
 0.1,  // Near
 10000  // Far
);
camera.position.set( 15, 10, 15 );
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFF00 );
light.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light );
var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x808080 );
light1.position.set( 20, 20, 20 );
scene.add( light1 );
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x00FFFF );
light2.position.set( -20, 20, -20 );
scene.add( light2 );
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFF00FF );
light3.position.set( -20, -20, -20 );
scene.add( light3 );
  
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5,16,16);
for(var i=0;i<sphereGeom.vertices.length;i++){
  var v = sphereGeom.vertices[i];
  if(v.y<0) v.y=0;
}
sphereGeom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
sphereGeom.computeFaceNormals();
sphereGeom.computeVertexNormals();

var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x808080 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, material );
scene.add( mesh );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xdddddd, 1);


(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still end up with the blank screen with the  "canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }"

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet shows that you have a typo on the opening `<style>` tag:

```
<title>My first Three.js app</title> &lt;style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
```

It should be:

```
<title>My first Three.js app</title> <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }</style>
```

I suspect that's why you're seeing the text being displayed on the page.

The canvas is probably coming up as 0x0 because of that so you cannot see the cube.

Tweak that style tag and see how it goes?

EDIT: In fact, I think the body tag will need to be set to 100% as well otherwise the document won't have any height. Perhaps try this style tag:

```
<style>
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried the second style tag and that cleared up the text displayed on the page. Unfortunately, I still cannot see the cube but maybe that might be due to my code in the body?

Comment: Yeah I would take a look at this and then view source - https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#BoxGeometry - I'm seeing you create a 700x700x700 box which as @manthrax pointed out probably puts you inside it. Also I'm not sure what happens when you set up a scene without putting in any lighting.

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Okay Ill check that out and also look into putting lighting!

Comment: Here is the tutorial: https://www.awwwards.com/creating-3d-cube-a-practical-guide-to-three-js-with-live-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong: I was calling the three.js file incorrectly.

It was:

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
```

but should have been:

```
<script src="./three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Threejs might be a bit big of a bite to take if you are struggling with this. There could be a million things why a “canvas” could look “blank”. From not even having the canvas to not painting it correctly.

Comment: If you loaded an html page with no JavaScript whatsoever you could have found these problems without the complexity that you have now.